# How to calculate the density function of Z = XY where X and Y are independent random variables with uniform distribution in (0, 1)?

Tags: statistics

I need to know how to calculate which is the density function of a random variable Z that arises from the multiplication of two independent uniform random variables X and Y in the interval (0, 1) (Z = XY)?

Since I need to know its density function to calculate P(Z <0.5).

Comment: Did you try the question yourself?

Comment: You don't need the density for the probability. What else have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to find information about it but I have found solutions that exceed my level, such as:https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.researchgate.net/publication/46507995_Product_of_independent_uniform_random_variables/amp
I am trying to think of other simpler solutions, but I can not find a simple way to extrapolate a probability distribution Z from the multiplication of two variables X and Y of uniform distribution. And estimating the probability by random sampling is not a possibility.